# Linking Cognito user pool ID with their facebook ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a Congnito identity pool with Congnito User Pool as well as Facebook as authentication provider.  I am able to register users with user pool as well as facebook.  Some of the users may initially register using user pool but later may want to use their facebook credential to login.

Currently my application is treating both of them as separate users.  How do I validate if a new login using facebook is already registered using user pool ?